# Trigger.io html fails for iPhone but same code works for android nexus 1

Tags: html, iphone, forms, submit, trigger.io

I've created a cut down version of the problem to see if that could solve it and of course tried many forum searches, unfortunately none of them seem to have a solution that works.

The problem is that a form fails to submit from an iPhone 3Gs v5.0.1(yet to test on any other iphones), a seperate window always opens up, but no data seems to be passed to the php form.

I've included my code, as well as a link to be able to view the data you've submitted. I'd really like to know if anyone else is able to submit from their androids but not iPhone?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="js/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style type="text/css">
            .container-narrow {
                margin: 0 auto;
                max-width: 700px;
                padding: 20px;
            }
            .container-narrow > hr {
                margin: 30px 0;
            }

            .jumbotron {
                margin: 60px 0;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .jumbotron h1 {
                font-size: 50px;
                line-height: 1;
            }

            p {
                font-size: 1.2em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <form target = "_blank" name="rating" action="http://www.stopandsearch.org/simpleupload.php" method="post" >    
            comment: <input type="text" name="comment">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see a link to view the failed uploads(as blank spaces) once you submit via the code above.

I'd be really grateful if someone could let me know if they also get the same issue in regards to iPhone failing but android succeeding, and of course if anyone knows of a solution, then I'd be over the moon!

I've tried ALOT of the forums, and although they seem to have the same issue, their solutions don't quite work.

Any advice on this would helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think iOS restricts you from POSTing data from an app to a external web page, so I would advise to use the forge.request.ajax method (you'll need to enable the request module).

Then you can do something like this:

```
<form id="comment" onsubmit="return false;">    
comment: <input type="text" name="comment">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="send_data();">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function send_data() {
  var comment = $('input[name="comment"]').val();
  if ( comment ) {
    forge.request.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://www.stopandsearch.org/simpleupload.php',
      data: { 'comment': comment },
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#comment').html( data );
      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert('Failed to save comment');
      }
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

This code will submit the comment via ajax so the user is not redirected to Safari, and the response from the server replaces the form if successful. You'll see that your comment will also successfully appear on the [comments page](http://www.stopandsearch.org/viewComment.php).

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thank you!!